# Would I Use "Freelancing" as Profession in My Passport?

Tags: professionalism

I am from Bangladesh. It's been 7+ years I am working as a Freelance Web Developer. I don't have any business license. I recently applied for a Passport where I noted profession as "Freelancing".

It was ok when applying, but the police verification says, I shouldn't use "Freelancing" as a profession. I could say it as a job, business etc.

I need to know if it's advisable to use "Freelancing" in anywhere as my profession.

Comment: Your profession is "web developer", isn't it? Whether you do it as a freelancer or for a company, that profession stays (basically) the same.

Comment: The appropriate tense would be "Freelancer". That's the job title. Freelancing is the subject. I don't know whether it's legal or not... or if it matters.

Comment: Freelance is the means you do your job, not the job itself.

Comment: You need to ask the passport office for your country, we can't advise you on suitability (although I'd say no, sounds like you saying "I don't have a job, I'll do anything"), voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.

Comment: @MaskedMan Since this question is asking about a passport, it may be better for [travel.se]

Comment: "Freelancing" isn't a profession any more than "Employed" is.  You're a web developer.

Comment: Thanks everybody for helping me getting the term cleared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say your profession is Web Developer, regardless of whether you're freelancing or work for a salary at a company developing websites.

Think of it this way, if you've worked 10 years as a Web Developer you've got 10 years of experience as a Web Developer, regardless of working as Freelancer or with a contract.

Same if you made bread, coded mobile apps or anything else. What you do and the work model are two different things.